# Trouble with plotting complex large function in Octave

Tags: octave

Hello Iam new with Octave and communications, and I'm trying to simulate different modulations using complex information signal as the following:

[image]

But even after I put points before each operator and all solutions that have come to mind I kept getting the same error result:

> error: conversion of 71.3086 to octave_idx_type value failed

This is my code:

```
f = 1e5;
T = 1/f;
t = 0:T/100:2*T;
a = (10^5).*t;
w = 2.*a*pi;
vi = 0.6.+0.6(e.^((-1.*(a.-42).^2)./9).+e.^((-1.*(a.-24).^2)./9).+e.^((-1.*(a.-6).^2)./9)).*sin(w./3).+0.3.*(e.^((-1.*(a.-47).^2)./9).+e.^((-1.*(a.-29).^2)./9).+e.^((-1.*(a.-11).^2)./9)).*cos(w);

plot(t./1e6, vi, 'b', 'LineWidth', 2)
grid on
xlabel('Time (ns)');
ylabel('vi (V)');
xlim([0 (2*T)/f]);
ylim([0 1.2]);
```

I don't know anymore what to try to plot this.

Anyway thanks for your attention. :)

Comment: The error is near the beginning of your equation. You need a `*` between the `0.6` and the open parenthesis: `vi = 0.6.+0.6 * (e^...`. If you break down these long calculations into small segments, it's much easier to locate the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Yes I made some variables to simplify the long function, and also had to review the fequencies, Reviewing that I got the plotted signal that I was expecteing to see, Thanks :D